# Create a trigger that inserts values into a new table when a column is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I've been looking at some previous answers on triggers on here but can't find what I need exactly but I'm sure my question  has been asked/answered before.

I'm trying to keep track of any changes to columnA and columnB in table1.

If this value changes I want to keep track of the values by inserting the existing value and the new Value into a different table with a date.

I've been looking at using something like this for the insert but not sure how to add get the existing and new values of the source table (table1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER NewTrigger ON table1
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO table2
        (columnA , columnB, todaysDate)
    .
    .

go
```

I need to use (I think) the

```
Before update ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
   .
   .
   .
BEGIN
```

and look through all the changes and insert these first then do the same after the Update?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should do what you need. You would have the `INSERT` statements below insert values indicating the operation performed into `MyLogTable`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_MyTable]
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE

AS 

DECLARE @INS int, @DEL int

SELECT @INS = COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED
SELECT @DEL = COUNT(*) FROM DELETED

IF @INS > 0 AND @DEL > 0 
BEGIN

    -- a record got updated, so log accordingly.

    INSERT INTO MyLogTable
    SELECT 'New Values', getdate() FROM INSERTED

    INSERT INTO MyLogTable
    SELECT 'Old Values', getdate() FROM DELETED

END

ELSE 
BEGIN

    -- a new record was inserted.

    INSERT INTO MyLogTable
    SELECT 'Insert', getdate() FROM INSERTED

END
```

If you wanted to you could also add columns from `INSERTED` and `DELETED` to your log table as well if you wanted to capture the actual column values that got inserted or updated.

Comment: ok cheers for the answer I'll take a look at this and come back to you.

Comment: Sorry I did want to keepn track of the actual values in the colummns that got inserted or Updated, how easily is that done?

Comment: Woohoo! :)  Regarding your last question, if you haven't already found a way, basically you'd just add any additional columns to the `INSERT` statements for insert or update, so that anytime the table is modified whatever columns you define will be updated with the before and after values.

Answer (score 5):

This is for all changes and all columns, but you can modify how you like:

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trMyTrigger]
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with caller queries select statements.
    -- if an update/insert/delete occurs on the main table, the number of records affected
    -- should only be based on that table and not what records the triggers may/may not
    -- select.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Determine if this is an insert,update, or delete action

    DECLARE @action AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @count AS INT
    SET @action = 'I' -- SET action to 'I'NSERT by default.
    SELECT @count = count(*) FROM DELETED
    IF @count > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @action= 'D' -- SET action to 'D'ELETED.
            SELECT @count = count(*) FROM INSERTED
            IF @count > 0
                SET @action = 'U' -- SET action to 'U'PDATED.
        END

    IF @action = 'D'
        -- THIS IS A DELETE RECORD ACTION
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO myBackupTable
        SELECT *,GETDATE() AS changeDate, 'DELETE' AS task FROM DELETED
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @action = 'I'
                 -- this is an INSERT record action
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO myBackupTable
                    SELECT *,GETDATE() AS changeDate, 'INSERT' as task FROM INSERTED
                END
             ELSE
                -- this is an UPDATE record action
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO myBackupTable
                    SELECT *,GETDATE() AS changeDate, 'UPDATE' as task  FROM INSERTED
                END
        END
```

Comment: I am not good in sql so asking sily question.Is this answer captures from all the tables present in DB or we have to give a particular table name?

Comment: This is for one table. You would have to write your own dynamic script to make the trigger work on multiple/all tables.

Answer (score 2):

create trigger trigge on abs
instead of update as

```
declare @idd int , @pricee money
  select @idd= ProductID from inserted 
  select @pricee = ListPrice from inserted 
  insert into prod values ( @idd , @pricee)
  print ' cannot change'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_MyTable]
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE

AS 

DECLARE @INS int, @DEL int

SELECT @INS = COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED
SELECT @DEL = COUNT(*) FROM DELETED

IF @INS > 0 AND @DEL > 0 
BEGIN

    -- a record got updated, so log accordingly.

    INSERT INTO MyLogTable
    SELECT 'New Values', getdate() FROM INSERTED

    INSERT INTO MyLogTable
    SELECT 'Old Values', getdate() FROM DELETED

END

ELSE 
BEGIN

    -- a new record was inserted.

    INSERT INTO MyLogTable
    SELECT 'Insert', getdate() FROM INSERTED

END
```