# mysql,SQL,trigger,many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, many-to-many

Hello I am new to MySQL db, i am struck in a situation where I want to have a bridge table between students and course. where one student can have many courses and one course can have many students. I want to have a auto simultaneous entry into the bridge table student_course table(bridge table) by implementing a trigger in insert but unable to achieve it.Kindly help.

table A
StudentID
StudentName

table B
CourseID
CourseName

Table Student_course
StudentID
CourseID

Comment: What have you attempted so far ? Your requirement is too broad. Please post some attempted code, in order for us to take a look at.

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931839/create-a-trigger-that-inserts-values-into-a-new-table-when-a-column-is-updated

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use the view for it. It will suit for ur requirement than triggers

```
CREATE VIEW Student_course AS
   SELECT * FROM tableA
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM tableB
```